# Kong :: Client IP missing in X-FORWARDED-FOR

Tags: kubernetes, kong, x-forwarded-for

Using Kong ingress controller (v2.1) in Kubernetes. Running in Digital Ocean.

The problem is that client IP is missing in X-FORWARDED-FOR header for HTTPS request, yet present on the HTTP request. I need to be able to see the IP on the HTTPS requests as well.

The value received in X-FORWARDED-FOR header on HTTP request is "<the-client-ip>, <the-k8s-node-ip>".
Yet in case of HTTPS request the value is "<the-k8s-node-ip>". The client-ip is lost.

Kong installed using Help. The most relevant part of config is:

```
proxy:
  enabled: true
  http:
    enabled: true
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-protocol: "http"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-algorithm: "round_robin"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-tls-ports: "443"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-tls-passthrough: "true"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the SLL Passthrough. You can't modify headers when using this configuration. You should rather use SSL termination, unless you have some specific compliance requirements.

Checkout the doc for more:
https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/networking/load-balancers/how-to/ssl-passthrough/

Comment: What you said is reasonable, but i changed the passthrough setting to false and nothing changed. 
service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-tls-passthrough: "false"

Comment: You need to upload your SSL certificate to the LB to be able to configure SSL termination (https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/networking/load-balancers/how-to/ssl-termination/) and pass `service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-certificate-id` annotation instead of `service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-tls-passthrough`.

Comment: Your approach is correct. Configured SSL termination. But the problem now is that DO LB terminates the SSL, then makes an HTTP request to an HTTPS port of Kong proxy. Couldn't find a way to configure the LB to either a) send HTTP request to HTTP port of Kong proxy, or b) send HTTPS request to HTTPS port of Kong proxy. Could you please take a look. THanks! https://github.com/digitalocean/digitalocean-cloud-controller-manager/issues/351